# Get identifier in URL w/ pretty URL format

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2

My url is this : `/backend/web/product/1`

on my ProductController :

```
namespace backend\controllers;
use Yii;
use backend\models\Product;

class ProductController extends \yii\rest\Controller
{
    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $product =  Product::find()->All();
        return $product;
    }
    public function actionView($product_id)
    {
        // how can I get 1 in my URL? so i can use it inside this function
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the pretty url for the pattern you showed is based on id. (you should check your config  urlManager component)

So try

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    // $id should contain 1 
     return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```